# Error: The Content Area Was Not Found in Your Page

Tags: shortcode

My site is running Generate Press theme and using Elementor as page builder.

My goal is to created a shortcode that will display a CPT and it's metafields. When i use the shortcode on a page it works fine. However when I use it under Elementor I get the following error when I try to edit the post in the backend:
"The Content Area Was Not Found in Your Page"
https://docs.elementor.com/article/56-content-area-not-found

Supposedly this is because the function the_content is missing.

I have tried adding the function to the shortcode, but still nothing. Elementor support wouldn't help. Maybe one you can reason why this is happening. Here you have the code:

```
               function vehiculos_func( $atts ){ 

    $arg = array (
        'post_type' => 'vehiculo'
    );    

    $query = new WP_Query($arg);





    if($query ->have_posts()) {
        //echo "<ul>";
           // echo '<div class="grid-container">';
          $html ="<ul>";
          $html .= '<div class="grid-container">';
            while ($query ->have_posts()) {


                $query->the_post();
                $year = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_year', true);
                $kilometers = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_kilometers', true);
                $transmission = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_transmission', true);
                $doors = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_doors', true);
                $seats = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_seats', true);
                $power = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_power', true);
                $color = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_color', true);
                $fuel = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vehicle_fuel', true);


               $html .= '<span class="nombre">'.get_the_title().'</span>'; 



                $html .= '<li class="grid-33">';
                $html .= '<div class="vehiculo">';
                $html .= '<div class="separa-20"></div>';
                $html .= '<span class="nombre">'.get_the_title().'</span>';
                $html .= '<p>'.get_the_content().'</p>';
                $html .= '<span class="atributo">'.$kilometers.'| '.$fuel.'| '.'Año //'.$year.'</span>';
                $html .= '<div class="separa-10"></div>';
                $html .= '<span class="precio">Desde 4000€';
                $html .= '<div class="separa-20"></div>';
                $html .= '<button type="button" class="btn-small btn-default">Ver //Coches</button>';
                $html .='</div>';
                $html .='</li>';  
            }
       $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= "</ul>";

    }
 return $html;   


}
add_shortcode( 'vehiculos', 'vehiculos_func' );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution, simple add " wp_reset_query(); " before the return

Comment: Since you're not really overwriting the main query it's more efficient to use [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: Thanks @Howdy_McGee
Now I am understand better the solution. The wp_reset_query() solved the problem but I didn't understand why.However the codex explanation of the wp_reset_data() function has solved all my doubts and now I have a better understanding of what is happening.